# AWS DMS with Filtered row-level data

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

How can one use AWS DMS or related open source tool to copy specific/filtered rows (e.g using a SQL Query) of a source table to target table.

Example: migrate table on redshift-prod (with larger number of nodes and higher compute) to redshift-dev (with smaller number of nodes and lower compute) - because of the difference in storage and compute you want to migrate only specified number of rows using a query to redshift-dev.

There is the option of unloading to s3 and copying to target table - that is not what we desire

we want to use AWS DMS or some other Open Source Tool to migrate some of the rows from the table to target without using the Unload and Copy approach

Thanks to the community

Comment: Redshift is NOT an available source for DMS.

You said that 
"There is the option of unloading to s3 and copying to target table - that is not what we desire"
What is wrong with that option, you just need to run a few commands in the right order...!


By the way : DMS does actually use the very same unload to s3 - copy - run some etl approach.